# Make a new connection to the database dynamically in sails using the connection string provided by user

Tags: sails.js

I am using sails 0.12 version and have to take the information about the database user want to use dynamically. The connection string must be provided by the users after the sails application has started. Is there a way is sails to do this?

Comment: As in the user connects to a database and runs queries or the user connects to a database and then the models you have configured use that database?

Comment: it's like connection string is provided in runtime and the models that are already configured use that database.

Comment: That is a big "no-no" from what I assume is the Sails point of view. If the intention is to run multiple environments like "development" and "production" then you should "NODE_ENV" for that purpose. Also a SailS application can meet lots of needs, but that one should be better suited for objection + knex.js side of things...

Comment: have you found better solution to it yet?